# Cannot connect to SQL Server 

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I installed new Visual Studio 2010. Now if I want to add the database sql file, it shows an error saying "server not found or it not installed".

I saw that SQL Server 2008 Express is being automatically installed along with Visual Studio. I did not customize the install in any way.

Please solve my issue, and remove the error so that I can connect to the database server.

Comment: Is the SQL server service running?

Comment: We need a bit more information here please.  When you installed Visual Studio, did you make sure that SQL Express (or is it MSDE) was included in the install?  If you just chose what you wanted to install, you might have missed that.  Also, what do you mean by "add the database sql file"?  Are you trying to create a connection to the SQL server?  If so, what type of credentials are you using?

Comment: i am not using customize installation while installing the visual studio. and i checked in program files there is a folder of microsoft sql server and microsoft sql server compact edition. i think this shows that i installed the sql server. and if i add the database.mdf file in my website or web application that time the error shows that the server not installed or not found. in my sql server configuration manager i checked that the sql server is not running. if i run it manually then it shows an error of check error log list like something.

Comment: no my sql server service is not running. if i starts it manually it shows an error of check error list log for more information something like that.

Comment: @user690855: it's not very helpful if you tell us there **is** an error when you start the service, but you **don't tell us WHAT error it is!!** Please check the error log and tell us what it says!

Answer (score 0):

Check the answers on this post: 
[Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error)

Then, if your SQL Server service needs to be re-started and will not re-start under the account you have configured, you may be able to select a different account provided you have Administrator rights.
To change the account under which the service runs, try:

All Programs | Microsoft SQL Server 2012 | Configuration Tools | SQL Server Configuration Manager | SQL Server Services ,  Right Click SQL Server (instance) , Properties, this account (radio),  Browse,  Advanced,  Find … then pick the account you like …  “NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
“, CLICK “Apply” << ( IMPORTANT !!! ) then try to re-start under the new account you just selected.

For an answer on which account to choose check this post:
https://serverfault.com/questions/217654/difference-between-nt-authority-network-service-and-nt-authority-system

Good Luck